# Getting crontab error on Xubuntu

Tags: linux, xubuntu, crontab

When running the command `crontab -e` i get the following error:

```
no crontab for 'myusername' - using an empty one
888
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: IMHO this is a notice, not an error message... or gets your cronjob not executed?

Comment: Are you sure you are using crontab corectly? crontab -e ... as you now know, this edits your crontab file using $EDITOR or $VISUAL, which defaults to vi. Maby try a man crontab and see some information about it

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using `ed` editor to edit crontab, do the below steps to fix this

1. Type in `contab -e`
2. Type `q` and click enter, this will exit you out of `ed` editor
3. Now make `vi` as your default editor by typing in below command

   ```
   EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi
   export EDITOR
   ```

This fixed the issue for me!